# Terraform aws_eks_node_group

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

I want to create a new node group with a specific Auto scaling group and launch template I am creating.

When running the following TF file:

```
resource "aws_launch_template" "jupyter-gpu-stage" {
  block_device_mappings {
    device_name = "/dev/xvda"
    ebs {
      volume_size           = 100
      volume_type           = "gp2"
      delete_on_termination = "true"
    }
  }
  name_prefix = "jupyter-gpu-stage-"
  image_id      = "ami-123456789"
  instance_type = "g4dn.2xlarge"
    
  network_interfaces {
    security_groups = [module.aws_eks.node_security_group_id]
  }  
}
    
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "jupyter-stage-gpu" {
  depends_on = [aws_launch_template.jupyter-gpu-stage]
  name_prefix = "eks-jupyter-stage-gpu-"
  max_size    = 100
  min_size    = 0
  desired_capacity = 0
  vpc_zone_identifier = var.subnet_ids  # Specify your subnet IDs here
    
  launch_template {
    id      = aws_launch_template.jupyter-gpu-stage.id
    version = aws_launch_template.jupyter-gpu-stage.latest_version
  }
}
    
    
resource "aws_eks_node_group" "jupyter-stage-gpu" {
  cluster_name  = module.aws_eks.cluster_name
  node_role_arn = module.aws_eks.eks_managed_node_groups["main"].iam_role_arn
  subnet_ids    = var.subnet_ids
    
  # Optional
  node_group_name_prefix = "jupyter-stage-gpu-"
    
  scaling_config {
    desired_size = 0
    max_size     = 100
    min_size     = 0
  }
    
  launch_template {
    id      = aws_launch_template.jupyter-gpu-stage.id
    version = aws_launch_template.jupyter-gpu-stage.latest_version
  } 
}
```

AWS still creates its own ASG and Launch Template.
How can I disable such behavior?
I want the node group to use the specific ASG and Launch Template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To whoever is looking for a solution to the same problem, I found the issue. The launch template was missing user_data information.
I passed it like this:

```
user_data = filebase64("${path.module}/user_data.sh")
```